# I need to convert "year" column from "numeric" in R. I need help in plotting trends for multiple countries

Tags: r

I need to convert "year" column from "numeric" in R. R recognizes my year eg (1993) column as numeric data. How do I fix this to enable me plot a 10 year trend for multiple countries on one plot.

Comment: The year alone does not make a full date, you would also need to have/specify a day and month, in order for R to recognize it as class "Date"

Answer (score 0):

Using `lubridate`s `ymd` and `truncated`

```
library(lubridate)

ymd(data.frame(Year = c(1956, 1990, 2000))$Year, truncated = 2)
[1] "1956-01-01" "1990-01-01" "2000-01-01"
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R using `paste0()` and coercing to a Date vector via `as.Date()`:

```
transform(
  data.frame(Year = c(1956, 1990, 2000)),
  Year = as.Date(paste0(Year, "-12-31"))
)
```